# How to remove page numbering for particular pages of your document in LaTeX?

Tags: page-numbering

`\thispagestyle{empty}` is not working...

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which `\documentclass` are you using? Where are you executing his command? As it stands, the current question is too vague to answer. Please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem.

Comment: Before closing, let us give the OP the time to add more details to his question.

Comment: This usually works as expected, so you have to give us some hints of why the hell it does not work for you. Our divinatory arts are limited. The best hint is always reduce a copy of your `.tex` file to a minimal working example. Remember: minimal. Remember: working (still compilable).

Answer (score 0):

No idea why, but that happened to me as well. The solution was to move `\thispagestyle{empty}` to another place in the text. Since then I bear in mind not to put this command at the very beginning of a page or right after `\begin{document}`.

To avoid a misunderstanding: it will work at the beginning of a page or a document, except that I encountered a strange case, where not.